# Django - Could not parse the remainder: '++_RS' from 'annovar.GERP++_RS'

Tags: python, json, django

I have a JSON value that comes directly from a DB that has this label

`GERP++_RS`

The offending code is basically this

`{{ annovar.GERP++RS}}`

In the template. The JSON contains those keys in it and cannot be modified.

This is part of a big dictionary and I need to display the correspondent value on a HTML page, but Django gives me this error

`Could not parse the remainder: '++_RS' from 'annovar.GERP++_RS'`

What would be best strategy to retrieve the value from this key? Would I need to process it before it gets to the template?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier was was to access the JSON value in the view and send to the template.